# Log world events

Tags: terraria

I am thinking to buy a Terraria dedicated server to host a little community and I would like to know if it is possible log server events, like:

- Players login/logout
- Players dead
- Boss spawn/defeats
- etc.

so that we can create a sort of diary. Do you know if server logging is available and which type of events can be logged?

Comment: I don't think the default Terraria server software does any event logging.  There may be some custom server software out there.

Answer (score 6):

[tMod](http://tmod.us/) is dedicated server software that allows you to write plug-ins that hook the events that you describe, their forums have some tutorials that get you started. Given that you directly log the hooks and only need single conditions on perhaps the mobs being killed, it shouldn't become to complex...

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do it unless you write your own server software or wrapper (or find a tool someone else already wrote; I'm aware of none).

What you could do is redirect the server output to a file and then parse that (`TerrariaServer 1> events.txt`), but out of your list, that pretty much only includes player log-ins.

Comment: Parsing is not a problem, I can write my own. Do you know where I can find more information about the output format and content?

Comment: @Drake The output is... well, the output, but in a text file instead of on your screen. As far as content goes, aside from the usual "saving world data" / "settling liquids" stuff, it's only player log-ins and chat messages I'm aware of. Death messages and boss fights are definitely not displayed.